# Check out stuck at "Please wait"

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ4FL.jpg)
im using parsian-bank Extension for opencart

When attempting to complete an order the Please Wait! message comes up and the order is processed correctly but the browser does not take the user to the checkout/success page instead it just remains on the confirmation page displaying Please Wait!
 please help me im use parsian-bank Extension

Comment: Seems this parsian-bank Extension is not default OC extension, so better if you will ask developer of this extension where is the problem.

Comment: there might be a problem in the controller file. It's not redirecting you to success page when action is succeeded. It is a payment-related issue, hence my sincere advice is to contact the extension developer.